# An understanding of a sentence - much + adverb

Tags: sentence-meaning

You’re driving **much** fast.

Does the sentence make sense to you, native speakers? I am wondering whether I could use "much" alone to modify an adverb.
If the sentence make sense, does it mean "you are driving very fast"?

Comment: That sentence is straight-up ungrammatical. I can understand your meaning, but no native speaker would consider it correct.

Comment: You're driving much too fast

Comment: You use "much" for  "very + adjective/adverb". Not correct.

Comment: It should be "very fast", to modify another adverb, "very" is used. And much can't modify adjective neither.

Answer (score 2):

*You're driving much fast.*

The sentence isn't correct grammatically.

You cannot use *much* in the structure of *much* + adverb. However, you can use it as an adverb in the form of *much* + a comparative or superlative adverb or adjective.  For example:

*You're driving much faster.*

You can also use the phrase *"much too"* in front of an adverb. (Do not confuse with *too much,* which is used before a noun)  For example:

*You're driving much too fast.*

Answer (score 0):

It may not look proper with 'much'.

Because, we *generally* use 'much' as an adjective and 'very' as an adverb. Typically, in this sentence, you want to use 'adverb' i.e. `How are you driving?`

So, it's

> You are driving *very* fast.

Comment: Whether the word being modified is comparative is important.  You can say *very fast* but not *\*very faster*, and you can say *much faster* but not *\*much fast*.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "You're driving much too fast." You still need the 'too', but adding 'much' intensifies 'fast' much more so than simply saying "You're driving too fast."